# Xcode 6 using target build settings in scheme arguments

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.1.1

In order to test localisation, I have an Xcode scheme configured to specify simulator locale settings.  The scheme appears as follows:[image: xcode scheme arguments]

```
-AppleLocale $(LANG)_$(COUNTRY)
-AppleLanguages ($(LANG))
```

Passing the above arguments to the simulator has the desired effect if `LANG` and `COUNTRY` are defined as build settings in the target.

[image: xcode target build settings]

For convenient automation, I'd like to be able to override the build settings from xcodebuild.  However, when I run the following to override the target build settings, the locale of the simulator remains unchanged.

```
xcodebuild test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme 'App UI Tests' -destination 'name=iPad Air' LANG=es COUNTRY=ES
```

It seems the default build settings from the target are used, regardless of any overrides specified at the terminal.

As an alternative, I could specify the locale code directly in the scheme.  Then I could duplicate the scheme for every locale.  It seems like a lot of duplication, but perhaps it is more the intended usage of schemes.

Am I missing something? Is this a feature of schemes by design, or could it be an issue with Xcode?

Comment: How about `-xcconfig filename`?

Comment: Nothing changes unfortunately.  I tried adding `-xcconfig esES.xconfig`.  esES.xconfig contains: LANG = es
COUNTRY = ES

Comment: And you are passing the same arguments to the test action (you only show the command line for the "run" action)?

Comment: Also worth pointing out: when I manually change the the COUNTRY and LANG values directly in the target, it has the desired effect.  I just can't override the target build settings.

Comment: Good point.  I've updated the question to show the test action instead.

Comment: Have you tried this approach?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410102/xcode-command-line-test-with-argument-passed-at-launch