# xcode command line test with argument passed at launch

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I have small problem with implementing xcodebuild command test at CI. I have tests related to specific device language, in xcode I can set "Arguments Passed On Launch" to -AppleLanguages (language). Can I pass that argument using xcodebuild?

My script looks like this

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme "MyAppTests" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.0' test
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably set via env variable. Run `xcodebuild -workspace <ws> -target <t> -configuration <c> -showBuildSettings` and grep for *-AppleLanguages*. Do you get any reasonable output?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`xcodebuild` is for build your app. You can use this command to run your app with specific language.

```
xcrun simctl launch <deviceid> <appid> -AppleLanguages "(pt-BR)"
```

Hera a sample with all steps to buil and run your app:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator8.4 -arch i386 install DSTROOT=YourAppFolder
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 6 (8.4 Simulator)"
xcrun simctl install booted YourAppFolder/Applications/YourApp.app
xcrun simctl launch booted com.yourdomain.yourapp -AppleLanguages "(pt-BR)"
```

Comment: It works for building and running app but not for running UI tests in specific language.